# .htaccess URL rewrite rule needs rewrite, but no need redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a main portal site and many sister sites. They all are hosted in a same hosting server.
All photos uploaded by the sister sites reside in the main site photo directory.
I have a URL rewrite rule in each `.htaccess` of all sister sites.

```
RewriteRule ^files/photos/(.*)$ http://mymaindomain.com/files/photos/$1 [NC,L]
```

According to this rule, all photos browsing from the sister sites would be mirror to the main site photo directory.
It is perfectly working fine when the image source is using in `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="http://mysistersitedomain.com/files/photos/blah.jpg" />
```

**The problem** is that when I open the URL in the browser (using "Open link a new tab" from the browser context menu), it is redirecting to `http://mymaindomain.com/files/photos/blah.jpg`.
I don't want the redirection because I don't want the users see that the photos reside in my main site.
I just want to keep the URL as it is in the `<img>` src. How can I do that?

It does work as I expected in my localhost.
`http://localhost/mysistorsite/files/photos/blah.jpg` is showing the image of `http://localhost/mymainsite/files/photos/blah.jpg`, but it keeps the URL unchanged.

So far I have known is that a redirect will not be issued to the destination unless I use the flag `[R]`. Otherwise, the current protocol, servername, and port number will be used to generate the URL sent with the redirect.

**[Edit]**
Here is my current directory structure in the server. Please assume that my sister sites are so far using sub-domains. Later I will have the sister site domains at the same level of `mymaindomain.com`.

```
/var/www/vhosts/mymaindomain.com/
                            |__httpdocs
                                |__files
                                    |__photos
                            |__mysister1.com
                            |__mysister2.com
```

Comment: The same redirect happens with you `<img>` element btw. - only you don’t _see_ it. If you don’t want an external redirect – then you can not give an absolute URL as the redirect target. Whether or not you can redirect internally between your different “sites” depends on the setup, i.e. whether they are sharing the same base directory or are implemented using different VirtualHost setups.

Comment: @CBroe, please check my edit. The absolute URL is the only option, right?

Comment: So is `/var/www/vhost/mymaindomain.com/` the common VHost base address for all of those domains (and the subdomains are implemented using rewriting already)? Otherwise, you can not do an internal redirect, because the subdomains will not be allowed to “read” form the `httpdocs` folder of the main domain.

Comment: @CBroe, Is it possible if I have another vhosts for the sister sites at the same level of `/var/www/vhosts/mymaindomain.com/`? For example, `/var/www/vhosts/mysisterdomain.com/`.

Comment: You can not “break out” of the document root that is set for a domain with rewriting (AFAIK). I think you’d probably be better of with not rewriting those requests at all, but just set up an [ALIAS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) for your subdomains/other domains – that way, you can request `http://mysistersitedomain.com/files/photos/blah.jpg` directly, but have the data served from another directory that you specified as ALIAS (for either `/files/photos/`, or `/files` if you need to serve other files from that directory as well).

Comment: @CBroe, I have the server config at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. All of my sister domains locate in `/var/www/vhosts/mymaindomain.com/`. So, that `httpd.conf` is a correct one to add those ALIAS(es) of all of the sister domains.